# Uninstalling a particular version of the .NET framework

Tags: uninstall, .net-framework

I have various .NET frameworks installed on my machine (up to v4.0). I am looking to remove and re-install .NET framework 2.0, because I think it is corrupt. Does it mean I have to uninstall everything that comes after v2.0, and then finally remove v2.0, and then do the reverse (install everything back)?

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step guide: [How to manually remove and then reinstall the .NET Framework 2.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908077)

You better follow this KB guide, because it will help you to **fully** remove the the .NET Framework from your OS.

Good luck.

Comment: In the following step http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908077# I cannot find the comment which says _Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 RTL x86 enu_

Comment: You got a 64 BIT Operating system?

Comment: no, I got 32-bit os. In my Add/Remove programs show that I have .net 2.0 sp1. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why you think your .NET 2.0 is corrupt but to answer your question each version of the .NET framework exists in isolation so you can just uninstall .NET 2.0 and then re-install it.